# How to remove Rafflesia off an island

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

i was joined by other players while on the island and last person who left blocked me in with Rafflesia by door entrance no one could come in and i could not get out had to turn off the game lost what i picked off the island ..guy chopped all the trees and blocked me from leaving

Answer (score 0):

The player who joined you was using a hacked 3DS and modded their game to be able to place the rafflesia, which is not supposed to appear on the island. There is no way to remove it unless you also use a hack that allows you to do so. A hack that lets you teleport or walk through walls might also let you get past it without removing it.